# Unhashable type "list" error while trying to compute the most frequent values

Tags: python, dictionary

This is my dictionary:

```
d = {'G': ['R'],
 'L': ['H'],
 'H': ['H', 'L', 'T', 'M'],
 'T': ['R'],
 'S': ['M', 'L', 'H'],
 'M': ['R']}
```

I am looking to find the most frequent values from this dictionary, in a list. Hopping to get the output:

```
['H', 'R']
```

This is the code I have tried running:

```
values_list = list(d.values())
max(set(values_list), key=values_list.count)
```

When running this code, I receive the error "unhashable type: 'list' ". I am wondering if there is an easy fix to this code to solve my issue.

Comment: What you have tried to fix this issue. Add that in question also.

Comment: How do you expect to get a list with 2 elements? `max` returns a single element. Also, `values_list` is a list of lists, not a list of strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
import collections
import itertools

values = [[x] if isinstance(x, str) else x for x in d.values()]
counter = collections.Counter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(values))

max_value = max(counter.values())  # maximum value
max_keys = [k for k, v in counter.items() if v == max_value] # getting all keys containing the `maximum`

print(max_keys)
```

---

**counter:**

```
Counter({'R': 3, 'H': 3, 'L': 2, 'T': 1, 'M': 2})
```

**max_keys:**

```
['R', 'H']
```

**OR**

```
from functools import reduce
from collections import Counter

values_list = list(d.values())
li = reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,values_list)
counter = Counter(li)
m = max(counter.values())
r = [k for k in counter if counter[k] == m]
```

---

**r:**

```
['R', 'H']
```